# How to get notified immediately about pushed commit on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, notifications

Is there a way to get a notification *immediately* **by e-mail or Telegram** when an author pushes a commit? I'm aware of RSS but it takes some time before refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

Most things that happens to an account, or repo on Github can be configured to send a [Webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) to a designated URL. There are also a number of services that will catch those notifications and perform some action. I have several setup myself for various repos, such as starting to run tests or code-quality (Travis and StyleCI) or just a notification via Slack.

There are also other services that can perform some user-specified action, such as sending you an email - like [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/services/github) and [zapier](https://zapier.com/apps/github/integrations/). It's also possible to write your own.